# How to plot data from multiple csv files on one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

With the code below, I get two separate plots the way I would like, minus the axis labels and correct date/time on the x axis but I'll learn that next, but I would like to have both series plotted on the same plot.

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    PATH = ('pathname...')
    fileNames = os.listdir(PATH)

    fileNames = [file for file in fileNames if '.csv' in file]

    for file in fileNames:
        df = pd.read_csv(PATH + file)
        df1 = df[df['Station Name'].str.contains('Precip')]

        df1.plot()

    plt.show()
```

the csv files I am loading look something like this

```
     Station Name,Sensor Serial Num,model and version,Slope,Offset,Averaging Time,Sampling Interval
     123456789,NA12345,FpRain ver 1.06,-2.4418566 ,-3.3988995 ,2.000 sec,0 ms
     Precip,02/01/2020,09:45:00,-2.19,
     Batt Voltage,02/01/2020,09:45:00,13.4,
     Temp In Box,02/01/2020,09:45:00,-2.58,
     Precip,02/01/2020,10:00:00,-2.19,
     Batt Voltage,02/01/2020,10:00:00,13.6,
     Temp In Box,02/01/2020,10:00:00,-2.17,
     Precip,02/01/2020,10:15:00,-2.19,
     Batt Voltage,02/01/2020,10:15:00,13.7,
     Temp In Box,02/01/2020,10:15:00,-1.72,
```

Comment: initiate an axis instance with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, then pass `ax=ax` to `df1.plot(ax=ax)` inside the loop.

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you for ending my headache!